# Can I plan a mission with DJI SDK without GPS?

Tags: dji-sdk

I'm trying to control the drone to fly autonomously, but in an area without GPS access. Will I be able to use the SDK to tell it to fly x meter forward/backward/up/down etc without GPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is YES. I rarely use GPS in my navigation task. The only difference is how complex you need to hardware/software to be

**DJI OSDK**

For most of my project in recent year, I use DJI OSDK ROS to fly the drone with pure LDIAR or camera. see example video from here. Inside it is running visual internal navigation with stereo node. I tried with DJI A3/N3/ M100/M210/M600. all works fine. Complex onboard hardware, but software simple and straight forward.
[image: errorenter image description here]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1AbfRENy3OQ&t=90s

**DJI MSDK or PSDK**

For other cases like DJI MSDK or PSDK(if you have access)  you can use other methods like stream down video stream and do on ground localisation and then send the control command out. See my video(this is not using DJI A3, but using similar concept. I drop this idea after school project as it is deemed not suitable for actual commercial application). It is PTAM with EKF for IMU fusion
[image]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6xNINp7nnDge

The code running behind is from here https://github.com/tum-vision/tum_ardrone.

The DJI MSDK is meant to replace this link mentioned in the tum_arrone https://github.com/AutonomyLab/ardrone_autonomy .

All you have to do is to modify the source code input and output system to as a android C++ lib. It is not easy job but I already have seen other people doing it. Its simple in hardware but more work in software

**DJI WSDK**

Even for the DJI windows SDK you can still use pure PTAM based approach on the feature-rich area. As shown in the image below. It is running semi direct visual odometry from ETH group. Its minimal effort in both hardware and software. The only problem is you need it to be a feature-rich area.

I quite disagree with @Ken as the optical flow is only meant for low-level/Microcontroller position hold. It is not meant for dynamic odometry/state  estimation. For high-level general localization and mapping, it requires at least a visual odometry/SLAM output. And not only low altitude, the medium to high altitude will also work as shown in the figure below

[image]

The Code for getting this image is available at here https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_svo

Comment: Thank you for all the details. Does this mean the video feed needs to be used for the flight? In my requirement, I'll need the camera to record something else. However, it is possible to attach an additional camera I believe if that is necessary.

Comment: If you need separate camera for user, then A3/N3/M210 would be your choice.  OSDK should have no issue in getting what you needed. MSDK can also be used, but you have to test on the video feed to see whether it can support dual transmission mode(aka master drone control and slave video control) . this one im` not very sure.

Comment: If you need outsource the project or buy a complete product, you can contact them https://www.avetics.com/. They will give you ready-made product that you needed

Comment: Thank you @DrYuanShenghai for the detailed answer. Can elaborate on what is required to convert the code to for for DJI MSDK? Or do you know if it has been done?

Comment: @Shaked I`m sorry, but not all code can be converted into msdk due to library compatibility issues. If you really want some feature, most likely you have to implement the feature from a very low level. i have a couple master students who tried to convert ros code into msdk. they all failed badly.

Comment: @DrYuanShenghai sorry to hear that. Thank you

Answer (score -2):

Since positioning relies very heavily on the aircraft's GPS system I cannot see how you can accurately control movements.  You will have other issues also since most autonomous flight operations will not start until there are 6 (or 7) locked satellites.

You will also find that the aircraft will lack the ability to hold position (except when it's low enough for the vision systems to hold position).

My suggestion would be to look into the Virtual joystick parts of the SDK but honestly I feel you will not be happy and the possibility to achieve what you ask above may not be possible.

Comment: It is quite possible to do . The minimal reqirement is a image stream. If have IMU, that would be great.  See the research paper below  Scale-Aware Navigation of a Low-Cost Quadrocopter with a Monocular Camera (J. Engel, J. Sturm, D. Cremers).
Camera-Based Navigation of a Low-Cost Quadrocopter (J. Engel, J. Sturm, D. Cremers).
Accurate Figure Flying with a Quadrocopter Using Onboard Visual and Inertial Sensing (J. Engel, J. Sturm, D. Cremers).